# How to get the new values while editing a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to update some records in my table using the **GridView Item templates**. It's like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdCursos" runat="server" CssClass="grdTable" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CourseID">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("[CourseID]") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nome">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCourseName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("[CourseName]") %>' Width="50"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCourseName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("[CourseName]") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="# de Questões">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaxQuestions" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("[CourseMaxQuestions]") %>' Width="20"></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMaxQuestions" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("[CourseMaxQuestions]") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data de atribuição">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCourseSince" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%#Bind("[CourseSince]","{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nome do arquivo">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileCourse" runat="server"/>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCourse" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("[CourseFileName]") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" EditImageUrl="~/site/edit.jpg" 
                        ShowEditButton="True" DeleteImageUrl="~/site/cancel.jpg" 
                        UpdateImageUrl="~/site/accept.jpg" CancelImageUrl="~/site/cancel.jpg" 
                        ShowDeleteButton="True" CancelText="Cancelar" DeleteText="Inativar" 
                        EditText="Editar" UpdateText="Atualizar"></asp:CommandField>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                </Columns>
```

As soon as I click in **Edit Link**, some of my GriView's columns become a TextBox which I can edit. Then, when I click update button it calls my `grdCursos_RowUpdating` method. The problem is that I can't get the **new values** the user gave as input. I call a `MsgBox` to show the values I want to update and it shows the old values only.

This is my method:

```
Protected Sub grdCursos_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles grdCursos.RowUpdating
    Dim updatingRow As GridViewRow = grdCursos.Rows(e.RowIndex) 'Recupera a linha que está sendo editada

    'Recupera os dados cadastrados
    Dim ID As Label = updatingRow.FindControl("lblID")
    Dim txtCourseName As TextBox = updatingRow.FindControl("txtCourseName")
    Dim txtMaxQuestions As TextBox = updatingRow.FindControl("txtMaxQuestions")
    Dim CourseFile As FileUpload = updatingRow.FindControl("fileCourse")

    MsgBox(String.Format("ID={0}, Nome do curso={1}, # de questoes={2}, Nome do arquivo={3}", ID.Text, txtCourseName.Text, txtMaxQuestions.Text, CourseFile.FileName))
    Exit Sub
    ....
```

How can I get the new values?

Comment: [e.NewValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx)

Comment: K. i'm not very comfortable with .NET yet. I change this instead of e.RowIndex in my first line? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: `e.NewValues`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx):

> Gets a dictionary containing the revised values of the non-key field
>   name/value pairs in the row to update.
>
> Use the NewValues property (dictionary) to access the values of the
>   revised non-key fields in the row to update.
>
> The NewValues property is automatically populated with the name/value
>   pairs of the revised non-key fields in the row. A separate entry is
>   added to the NewValues property for each non-key field in the row.
>
> To determine the field name of an entry, use the DictionaryEntry.Key
>   property of a System.Collections.DictionaryEntry object contained in
>   the NewValues dictionary. To determine the value of an entry, use the
>   DictionaryEntry.Value property.
>
> Note
>
> The primary key field or fields are not included in this dictionary.
>   To access the values of the primary key field or fields, use the Keys
>   property. To access the original values of the non-key fields in the
>   row, use the [OldValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.oldvalues.aspx) property.

Example:

```
Sub CustomersGridView_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)

    ' Use the CopyTo method to copy the DictionaryEntry objects in the 
    ' NewValues collection to an array.
    Dim records(e.NewValues.Count - 1) As DictionaryEntry
    e.NewValues.CopyTo(records, 0)

    ' Iterate through the array and HTML encode all user-provided values 
    ' before updating the data source.
    Dim entry As DictionaryEntry
    For Each entry In records

      e.NewValues(entry.Key) = Server.HtmlEncode(entry.Value.ToString())

    Next
End Sub
```